# How do I select /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs in Plesk for Git?

Tags: ubuntu, github, plesk

In Plesk, I want to configure the automatic deployment using Git.

My default path for index.html is this:

```
/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs
```

This path can not be selected in Plesk:

[image]

I don't really want to change my default page location if I don't really have to.

How do I select my path "/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs"?

Thank you!